# Are any of the major CPAN or core Perl libraries succeptible to "Zip Slip" vulnerability?

Tags: perl, security

There has been a recent [notification of a major security vulnerability called "Zip Slip"](https://snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability) which affects numerous libraries in various languages (especially Java, but also JavaScript, GO, Ruby and Python).

Since this is clearly not limited to compiled languages, I was interested if any of the major Perl libraries (CPAN or core Perl) were succeptible, but Googling for `"Zip slip"+Perl` didn't produce any useful results.

Are any of the major CPAN or core Perl libraries susceptible to "Zip Slip" vulnerability?

Answer (score 3):

[`Archive::Tar`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Tar), for one, can be used to *create* archive files that can trigger this vulnerability. The current version defines the variable [`$Archive::Tar::INSECURE_EXTRACT_MODE`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Tar#$Archive::Tar::INSECURE_EXTRACT_MODE), set to false by default, that would allow this vulnerability to be exploited. This variable was introduced in v1.36 (2007); older versions of this distribution [are always susceptible to this exploit](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=30380).